# query_string is not returning expected result in ES 7.7

Tags: elasticsearch

I have recently upgraded Elasticsearch from 5.5 to 7.7.
While running my automation test suite, I found that `query_string` in ES 5.5 was returning me expected documents but ES 7.7 is returning empty results.
I noticed this issue only when I search with multiple words where term is present in different fields of a document. Please have a look on my example below:

My indexed document is like below

```
{ field1: "Hello Nik", field2: "NYC" }
```

_mappings:

```
"field1" : { "type" : "text", "fields" : { "keyword" : { "type" : "keyword", "ignore_above" : 256 } } }
```

Same mapping is there for field2.

My query snippet:

```
"query_string": { "query": "Hello NYC", "default_operator": "AND" }
```

The above query works perfectly fine with ES 5.5 and getting result successfully. But in ES 7.7 above query not able to search particular document and returning empty result.

Could you please suggest why ES 7.7 is not returning expected result ?
Are there any changes in search query algo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning related to `query_string` as mentioned in the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)**

> `query_string query` returns an error for any invalid syntax, it is
> not recommended to use the `query_string` query for search boxes.
> Refer to this  to know more about this.

Following are the various ways of implementing search query for the same data (as mentioned in the question)

**Search Query using `query_string`:**

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "Hello AND NYC",
            "fields": ["field1", "field2"]
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Query using `simple_query_string`:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string" : {
        "query": "Hello NYC",
        "fields": ["field1", "field2"],
        "default_operator": "and"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query using `multi_match`:**

```
{
      "query": {
        "multi_match" : {
          "query":      "Hello NYC",
          "type":       "cross_fields",
          "fields":     [ "field1", "field2"],
          "operator":   "and" 
        }
      }
    }
```

**Search Query using `bool query`:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "Hello NYC",
            "fields": ["field1","field2"],
            "type": "cross_fields",
            "operator": "AND"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my-index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.87546873,
        "_source": {
          "field1": "Hello Nik",
          "field2": "NYC"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Update 1:**

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "Hello AND NYC"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @PKhode did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you

Comment: I am clueless why its not working with query_string. official documentation has clearly stated that "query to create a complex search that includes wildcard characters, searches across multiple fields, and more". Also my search term is valid and es is not complaining about any invalid terms.

Comment: @PKhode I have stated this `query_string query returns an error for any invalid syntax, it is not recommended to use the query_string query for search boxes.` in the beginning of my answer, as its a warning that is mentioned in the ES documentation, documentation clearly states that `If you don’t need to support a query syntax, consider using the match query. If you need the features of a query syntax, use the simple_query_string query, which is less strict.`

Comment: @PKhode please go through my updated answer, and let me know if this search query works for you, I have tested it in my local with ES version 7.x and it is giving correct result

Comment: @PKhode the snippet of query_string which you have given in the question `"query_string": { "query": "Hello NYC", "default_operator": "AND" }`, gives the following error `Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [query_string].`, this error may be because you are missing `query` section in the body of search query. Can you please try the updated search query or any of the search query(acc to your requirement) mentioned in the answer and let me know if this works for u

Comment: @PKhode did u get a chance to go through my answer, any luck with it ?

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I am still using query_string and added type as 'cross_fields' to let es know to search against all fields.